# IndexError: list index out of range python orb

Tags: python, opencv, orb

can some help me with the error as i am new to the coding with opencv

```
def track_target(self, frame):
    self.cur_keypoints, self.cur_descriptors = self.detect_features(frame)
    if len(self.cur_keypoints) < self.min_matches:
        return []
    matches = self.feature_matcher.knnMatch(self.cur_descriptors, k=2)
    matches = [match[0] for match in matches if len(match) == 2 and match[0].distance < match[1].distance * 0.75]
    if len(matches) < self.min_matches:
        return []
    matches_using_index = [[] for _ in range(len(self.tracking_targets))]

    for match in (matches):
        matches_using_index[match.imgIdx].append(match) 
    tracked = []
    for image_index, matches in enumerate(matches_using_index):
        if len(matches) < self.min_matches:
            continue
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For this question, it would be helpful for you to provide the error stack trace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ar1.py", line 144, in <module>
    VideoHandler().start()
  File "ar1.py", line 95, in start
    tracked = self.pose_tracker.track_target(self.frame)
  File "ar1.py", line 40, in track_target
    matches_using_index[match.trainIdx].append(match) 
IndexError: list index out of range          @ Karin please have a look

Comment: can someone help me plzz